# How to communicate MainWindow.xaml and UserControl.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a changing views :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="DashboardTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:Dashboard}">
        <views:Dashboard DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Dashboard has textbox named "Output" And my problem is i can't access Dashboard's textbox from MainWindow is there anything i can do to make that happen? And if i put like  something like that then i can't change the view to otherviews

Comment: Where are you accessing this? In code behind or in XAML.

Comment: If you write `DataContext="{Binding}"` (which is actually redundant) it seems likely that the elements in the Dashboard's XAML directly bind to properties of the Dashboard view model class (where these two identical names are totally confusing). Which other "communication" do you need?